# How to accept the character " ' " only when the rest of the expression matches?

Tags: regex, parameters

So I'm trying to resolve this problem, but I don't know how to solved it:

Regular Expression I have:

```
^(AND\()(\d{1,3})(\,\d{0,3})*\)$
```

And the values I need to accept are:

```
AND(9,29)
AND(10)
```

But this expression is also accepting `AND(9,)`, with a comma but without a number next to it. How can I improve my expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(AND\()(\d{1,3})(?:,(\d{1,3}))?\)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPxGJL/1)

Some change notes:

- `(?:...)?` - an optional *non-capturng* group is used (inside, there is a capturing group for the number)
- `\d{0,3}` is replaced with `\d{1,3}` to avoid matching a `,` without a number after
- `(?:...)*`  is changed into `(?:...)?` since only two numbers are expected inside the parentheses.